# CreateAsyncThunk with custom actions in separate files

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

Maybe this is anti pattern but still I wanna see if this is possible

When using `createAsyncThunk` (e.g `fetchDataThunk` ) you are getting back 3 actions
`fetchDataThunk.pending`, `fetchDataThunk.fulfilled`, `fetchDataThunk.rejected`.

Is there a way to have the actions in separate files and pass them as params to the thunk ? I wanna avoid importing my thunk file on my reducer completely.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what your motivation is? The idea in modern Redux is to have thunk and slice in the same file, and exporting the actions separately doesn't give you any benefits. But of course you could just `export const { pending, fulfilled, rejected } = fetchDataThunk` -  is that what you're looking for?

Comment: The `pending`, `fulfilled`, and `rejected` actions are generated ***by*** `createAsyncThunk`, so you can't declare them separately and pass them to `createAsyncThunk`. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve for here?

Comment: My main problem is the need of having to import thunk file into the reducer file in order to use the actions. Ideally I would like to have my actions into separate files like we used to have in the traditional redux structure and import those separately on reducer and thunk files.

Reducers are being used into `configureStore` so having other dependencies from thunk can create various issues. ( in my case the `router` was being used by a thunk and it is accessing the `store` and the store has not been configured yet which is forbidden.

Comment: @phry no that won't be enough because I will end up importing the `thunk` file on the `reducer` again.

Comment: @phry I think the main question here is whether the actions should be separated than the thunk in terms of file structure. The argument of the author is that it introduces redundant dependencies leading to circular depedndencies in the project.
I think it makes the dependency tree more clear to be separated and this is something you can consider for your library. 
At the same time I believe the thunk should perform one and only one task and avoid external dependencies. 
(e.g. fetch data put them in the store)

Comment: A circular reference like that should usually be okay as long as it is not immediately executed - if you only access the `router` inside of your thunk, but do not synchronosuly execute your thunk before the `router` is populated, that *should* work fine, unless you work with an older bundling setup.
You can avoid something like this, though, by putting the `router` into your `thunk` `extra` on store creation, as you can access that from your `thunk` without an `import`.

Comment: This wont solve my problem because it will just end up again on importing the router in the store file where `configureStore` is being called. 

You see in my router file I am using the `store` object because I have `react-router-dom`  `loader` functions there that need to dispatch certain actions.

In that case you end up using the store without it being configured. You see the circular import issue ?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible. All you need to do is to create your action handler functions in a separate file, and the call them from the `createAsyncThunk` function.

Here is your `Actions.ts` file:

```
export const fetchUsersPending = () => ({ type: 'FETCH_USERS_PENDING' } as const)
export const fetchUsersFulfilled = (data: any) => ({ type: 'FETCH_USERS_FULFILLED', payload: data } as const)
export const fetchUsersRejected = (error: string) => ({ type: 'FETCH_USERS_REJECTED', payload: error } as const)
```

And then your `Thunk.ts` file:

```
import { fetchUsersPending, fetchUsersFulfilled, fetchUsersRejected } from "./Actions.ts"

export const fetchUsersThunk = createAsyncThunk(
  'fetchUsers',
  async (params: any, { dispatch }) => {
    try {
      dispatch(fetchUsersPending())
      const response = await fetchRequestFunction(params)
      dispatch(fetchUsersFulfilled(response.data))
      return response.data
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(fetchUsersRejected(error.message))
      throw error
    }
  }
)
```

Edit: This is kind of outdated `Redux` pattern. Most people now use [RTK-Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/rtk-query) for handling consumes and mutations. It is easy to learn and implement, and reduces the code redundancy. I wrote my own implementation of this before it was even released, circa 2020 when I was working on a complex ERP System, I saw the redundancy problem introduced by Redux and solved it by creating a standardized fetching class and eventually I didn't have to write `fetch` or `createAsyncThunk` code. It was all automatically generated from my `createHandler` function. Here is an example:

```
readUsers: createHandler({
    name: "user/read_users",
    method: "GET",
    route: "users/crud",
    skipAuth: false,
    pending: (state: SliceInterface, action) => setPending(state, "users.read", "Loading users... Please wait."),
    fulfilled: (state: SliceInterface, action) => {
        state = setFulfilled(state, "users.read", "Users loaded successfully.")
        for (const user of action.payload.users) 
            state.users.data = insertInHash(state.users.data, user, "id")
        return state
    },
    rejected: (state: SliceInterface, action) => setRejected(state, "users.read", action.payload.msg || "Error loading users")
}),
```

And here is an example usage in my component:

```
const { data: users, isLoading: isUsersLoading } = useConsume({ 
    action: () => UserActions.readUsers({ args: { id: user_id} }), 
    accessor: state => state.user.users 
}) as ConsumeResponse<Array<Users.User>>
```

You can write your own implementation like me, or you can just use the RTK-Query tool provided by Redux. Mine is quite a bit faster from my test cases, as is usually the case when you write a use-case-specific tool instead of a general-purpose tool.

Comment: Hi, I'm the person that invented `createAsyncThunk`. Please don't do this. You are reimplementing a second `createAsyncThunk` on top of `createAsyncThunk` here, in an old style of Redux that isn't used any more. `createAsyncThunk` already does the dispatching of actions you described in this answer, that's it's purpose.

Comment: @phry As redux is largely subjective in terms of its implementation, I don't see an issue with my implementation, especially since it performs better and provides a much cleaner code with much less redundancy.

Comment: I'm talking about the upper half, the `createAsyncThunk` that also dispatches additional actions. Since `createAsyncThunk` also dispatches actions, you now dispatch 2 pending, 2 fulfilled and 2 rejected actions, and you introduced a bug that would dispatch fulfilled *and* rejected actions assuming that a react render triggered by the fulfilled action would throw.

Comment: A correct use of `createAsyncThunk` in this case would be `export const fetchUsersThunk = createAsyncThunk('fetchUsers', fetchRequestFunction)` and I can't see how in comparison your suggestion would be cleaner with less redundancy.

Comment: @phry So then edit the code accordingly, or provide your answer and I will delete mine?

Comment: I have asked a follow-up question to their question, without further details I assume that this is a XY problem and directly answering their question will lead them in the wrong direction.